# Polybase External Tables vs. OPENROWSET serverless sql pool architecture

Tags: serverless, azure-synapse

I am in search of performance benchmarks for querying parquet ADLS files with the standard dedicated sql pool using external tables with polybase vs. serverless sql pool and OPENROWSET views.
From my base queries on a 1.5 billion record table, it does appears OPENROWSET in serverless sql pool is around 30% more performant given time for the same query, but what are the architecture that power that? Are there any readily available performance benchmarks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The architecture behind Azure Synapse SQL Serverless Pools and how it achieves such a strong performance is described in this paper, it is called "Polaris".

http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol13/p3204-saborit.pdf

Performance benchmarks have been published on multiple blogs. Be aware that this can only be a snapshot in time as those features are being improved constantly.